# Срабатывание на всех элементах

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт. Это кнопка. Из-за querySelector срабатывает только первая кнопка на странице. Как сделать, чтобы срабатывал на других?

Кнопки выглядят так:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.submit-button'),
  stateMsg = document.querySelector('.pre-state-msg');

const updateButtonMsg = function() {
  button.classList.add('state-1', 'animated');

  setTimeout(finalButtonMsg, 5);
};

const finalButtonMsg = function() {
  button.classList.add('state-2');

  setTimeout(setInitialButtonState, 1250);
};

const setInitialButtonState = function() {
  button.classList.remove('state-1', 'state-2', 'animated');
};

button.addEventListener('click', updateButtonMsg);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600");
@-webkit-keyframes short-press {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
            transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes short-press {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
            transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}



.hide {
  display: none;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .75em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 120px;
  line-height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #81c003;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.submit-button:hover, .submit-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.submit-button.animated {
  -webkit-animation: 0.75s short-press cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) forwards;
          animation: 0.75s short-press cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) forwards;
}
.submit-button > span {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.submit-button > span.pre-state-msg {
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition-delay: .75s;
}
.submit-button.state-1 .pre-state-msg {
  margin-top: 0px;
  /* margin-top: -38px; */
}
.submit-button.state-2 .pre-state-msg {
  margin-top: -42px;
}
```

```html
<button class="submit-button state-0">
 <span class="pre-state-msg">ADD TO CART</span>
 <span class="done-state-msg hide">DONE!</span>
</button>
<button class="submit-button state-0">
 <span class="pre-state-msg">ADD TO CART</span>
 <span class="done-state-msg hide">DONE!</span>
</button>
<button class="submit-button state-0">
 <span class="pre-state-msg">ADD TO CART</span>
 <span class="done-state-msg hide">DONE!</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Нужно использовать `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как пример с `querySelectorAll`

```js
const stateMsg = document.querySelector('.pre-state-msg'),
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.submit-button');

const updateButtonMsg = function(e) {
  this.classList.add('state-1', 'animated');
  setTimeout(() => finalButtonMsg(this), 2000);
};

const finalButtonMsg = function(e) {
  e.classList.add('state-2');
  setTimeout(() => setInitialButtonState(e), 1250);
};

const setInitialButtonState = function(e) {
  e.classList.remove('state-1', 'state-2', 'animated');
};

buttons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', updateButtonMsg);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600");
@keyframes short-press {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .75em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 120px;
  line-height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #81c003;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.submit-button:hover,
.submit-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.submit-button.animated {
  -webkit-animation: 0.75s short-press cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) forwards;
  animation: 0.75s short-press cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) forwards;
}

.submit-button>span {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.submit-button>span.pre-state-msg {
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition-delay: .75s;
}

.submit-button.state-1 .pre-state-msg {
  margin-top: 0px;
  /* margin-top: -38px; */
}

.submit-button.state-2 .pre-state-msg {
  margin-top: -42px;
}
```

```html
<button class="submit-button state-0">
 <span class="pre-state-msg">ADD TO CART</span>
 <span class="done-state-msg hide">DONE!</span>
</button>

<button class="submit-button state-0">
 <span class="pre-state-msg">ADD TO CART</span>
 <span class="done-state-msg hide">DONE!</span>
</button>

<button class="submit-button state-0">
 <span class="pre-state-msg">ADD TO CART</span>
 <span class="done-state-msg hide">DONE!</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Нажимаю на вторую или третью, анимация на первой срабатывает.

Comment: Ну конечно, у вас же анимации привязаны к button а это первая кнопка, вам нужно переписать немного код

Comment: Вот подправил видно когда отрабатывает

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрел. При смене цвета бэкграунда срабатывает как надо. Я добавил то, что должно в CSS происходить. Как раз эта анимация не срабатывает

Comment: Видимо дело не в Javascript, а в CSS

Comment: Ну вообще возможно длина анимации больше чем вы выделяете время, так никто не делает, лучше все анимации описать в одном месте, или чисто в css или в js. А вообще тяжело помочь не видя css.

Comment: CSS добавлен к коду вопроса сверху.

Comment: Уже, да, просто не стоит править шапку если Вам начали помогать, тяжело понять о чем говорим. Код поправил, вот так нужно чтобы работали ваши стили.

Comment: Насчет правки шапки буду знать. Спасибо вам большое! Всё работает как надо.